# Datetimepicker hidden when using in grid

Tags: laravel, datetimepicker

I  have a grid with several input fields, also a datetimeinput. On click the calendar is partially hidden:
[image]

If i set overflow-y: visible; it's working, but the grid leaves the div on the right side.

[image]

I searched longtime and tried many given solutions, but nothing works.

Comment: I think there is no solution for that "problem". You have content inside an scrollable frame, and the calendar is part of the content of that frame. By definition it must be inside that frame, and you must scroll down to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom solution:

```
    $(".delivery_date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    widgetPositioning: {
        horizontal: 'auto',
        vertical: 'bottom'
    }
});

var tableContentHeight;

$('.delivery_date').on("dp.show",function (e) {
    tableContentHeight = $('#table_content').height();
    var closestRow = this.closest( "tr" ).id;
    var closestRowPosition = $('#' + closestRow).position();
    if(closestRowPosition.top + 250 > tableContentHeight){
        var newTableContentHeight = tableContentHeight + 250;
    }
    $( "#table_content" ).height( newTableContentHeight);
});

$('.delivery_date').on("dp.hide",function (e) {
    $( "#table_content" ).height( tableContentHeight);
});
```